# How to inherit the default generic types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Does TypeScript have the null type that inherits the default generic types?

Example:

```
type Foo<T = number, U = string> = { t: T, u: U }
type Bar = Foo<?, boolean> // Should be Foo<number, boolean>, but cannot input 'number'
```

Comment: Did you mix up `Foo` and `Test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know this is not possible right now.
This might be something that could be covered by [partial type argument inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) in the future.